# Would the tension in the ropes increase in this question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image: Part i)]

[image: Part ii)]

I was doing a test at school on circular motion and one of the questions has been attached. Part i) was fine but I am confused by part ii). My initial reaction was that the tension would increase because there would need to be a centripetal force for the ring to rotate (and that is what the mark scheme says) but then I thought that if the tension increased, the sum of the vertical components of the tension in the ropes would be greater than the weight of the ring and so the ring would lift up, meaning that the ropes would no longer be taut and there would be no tension at all. My conclusion was that if I considered the ring when stationary, there is already a horizontal component of the tension acting inwards on a given section of the ring but since the ring isn't accelerating, there must also be an outwards force of equal magnitude to give a resultant force of 0. Therefore, when the ring rotated, this outwards force would decrease, leaving a net resultant force towards the centre and the tension would remain exactly the same. I am curious about where I've gone wrong in my reasoning so if anyone could give me the correct explanation, I would be grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the problem states that the ring is **rigid** the radius of the ring must stay at $1.26\,\rm m$.
From the geometry of the arrangement the angle the strings make with the vertical $\theta = \tan^{-1} \dfrac{1.26}{3.60}$.
This angle does not change whether or not the ring is rotating.
Since there is no vertical motion the sum of the vertical components of the tensions in the 8 strings must be equal in magnitude to the weight of the ring.
The sum of the horizontal components of the tensions in the string will provide all or some of the forces necessary fo the ring to undergo centripetal accelerations.

In the real world rotating the ring a low speed will result in the ring being compressed by the string tensions so that the net horizontal force on every element of the ring towards the centre pole will provide the centripetal acceleration of each element.

Rotating the ring above a certain speed would cause the ring to elongate and so set up tensions in the ring the (horizontal) components of which acting towards the thin pole would provide (together with the horizontal components of the string tensions) the forces which enable the ring the undergo centripetal accelerations.
In this example the the compression and elongation of the ring is assumed to be negligible (zero) as the ring is rigid.
The ring cannot rise up because, as you have stated, that would result in the strings no being under tension.

So there is an error in the mark scheme if it states that the tensions in the strings change when the ring is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

The tension in the **ring** (not the ropes) provides the centripetal force.

In the absence of gravity, the ring could rotate by itself without any need for ropes, because it is rigid. Internal forces prevent if from flying apart. The ropes are only required to prevent the ring from falling under gravity. This gravitational force does not change if the ring rotates.

If the ring were not rigid but consisted of 8 disconnected segments, the roundabout  would be effectively 8 conical pendulums. There is now no internal force between the segments, so the centripetal force would have to come from the tension in the ropes. In order to rotate faster, the ropes would have to rise to provide more centripetal force, and the segments would get further apart.

Comment: I'm not sure I have explained myself very well. I understand that the tension provides the centripetal force but if the tension increases to provide the centripetal force, surely the ring will lift since the vertical component of the tension will be greater than the weight (not because the weight has decreased but because the tension has increased) and the ropes will no longer be taut?

Comment: @MatthewBarber, there are two tensions in this problem.  There is the tension in the ropes that support the ring, and there is the tension in the ring that results from its circular motion.  The tension in the ring exists only in the plane of the ring, so the ring will not "lift", regardless of how fast the ring is spinning.

Comment: That's what I thought during the exam but the mark scheme said that the tension in the ropes would increase to provide the centripetal force. My question is effectively, is the mark scheme wrong?

Comment: Yes, the mark scheme is wrong.